# Como fazer alterações utilizando jQuery dentro de um iFrame em outro domínio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

Olá preciso carregar um site parceiro dentro do meu site. Porém gostaria de realizar alterações na estilização utilizando jQuery de preferência.

Achei a solução abaixo para manipular os elementos.

```
$('.header__logo', window.parent.meuIframe.document).style["display"] = "none";
```

Porém ao executar me deparei com o seguinte erro:

```
blocked a frame with origin null from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

Esse tipo de alteração é possivel de ser realizada, teria alguma forma de não cair na same-origin policy? .

Answer (score 0):

Sendo de outro dominio estás naturalmente sujeito a [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Não sabendo qual tua linguagem de servidor, podes tentar obter o conteúdo html da página e guardar esse conteúdo html do teu lado e gerar o iframe a partir daí.

Em alternativa, dá uma olhada no [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)